# React CSS Modules: any reason to -not- extract all CSS to a static file?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules

I have built my app with [React Boilerplate](https://www.reactboilerplate.com/), and have been surprised to find all my CSS modules are not generating CSS as I thought, but the CSS is instead generated from JS and embedded in the header of the page.  The image below shows just some of the many, many style elements that appear in my header after the page has loaded.

[image: list of style elements embedded in page head]

For development, I can see this making sense for HMR etc.  However, for a production build, it is not what I would expect.

I would think the most performant build (ie, best) would be a static CSS file alongside the js.  In fact, in our production build there is a lot of stutter as the site loads and applies styles to the elements in a staggered manner.

It seems straight-forward to build a static CSS file, so why isn't it the default (especially for RBP, whose major claim is that it is production-ready).  After 5 mins of searching I found https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin, which seems to do exactly what I want.

Is there a benefit to dynamically adding the CSS in the document header as pictured? Is there anything we would lose if we built a static CSS document instead?

Comment: When you say "this method" are you referring to RBP's method of embedding it into the header of the page?

Comment: yes - where it seems like every css file imported in the app ends up in a dynamically created style tag in the header